# Android EditText/TextView how to make each word start with uppercase and all remaining characters of words to be lowercase

Tags: android, android-edittext, uppercase, lowercase

I have already used following options to make each starting letter of a word Uppercase

```
 <EditText
    android:inputType="text|textCapWords"/>
```

While typing the user has option on the keyboard to change the case of letter i.e. the user with this option can easily type `lowercase` letters.

Further,I want text on my `EditText` to be on this format

`Each Starting Letter Of A Word Must Be In Uppercase And All Other Letter Of The Word Be In Lowercase`.

Meaning,when the user inputs

`each StArting LeTTer of a word musT be in uppercase and all other leTTer of the word be in lowercase`

, it will be automatically converted to above format.

I have tried using `TextWatcher` and `string.split(\\s+)` to get all the words and then make each and every word to follow the above format. But I always end up getting error.
So if there is any solution,it would be great.I want this to work in the manner `InputFilter.AllCaps`.

This is my code so far

```
private void changeToUpperCase(String inputString) {
    if (inputString != null && inputString.trim().length() > 0) {
        // businessName.addTextChangedListener(null);
        String[] splitString = inputString.split("\\s+");
        int length = splitString.length;
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            String convertedString = splitString[i];
            stringBuffer.append(Character.toUpperCase(convertedString
                    .charAt(0)));
            stringBuffer.append(convertedString.substring(1).toLowerCase());
            stringBuffer.append(" ");
        }
        Log.i("changed String", stringBuffer.toString());
        // businessName.setText(stringBuffer.toString());
        stringBuffer.delete(0, stringBuffer.length());
        stringBuffer = null;
        // businessName.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
}
```

This function I am calling from `TextWatcher`, `afterTextChanged(Editable s)`

Comment: Can you show your code and the error you get ?

Comment: have a look http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/WordUtils.html

Answer (score 25):

In the layout `xml`, add `android:capitalize="sentences"`

The options for `android:capitalize` are following :

`android:capitalize="none"` : which won't automatically capitalize anything.

`android:capitalize="sentences"` : which will capitalize the first word of each sentence.

`android:capitalize="words"` : which will capitalize the first letter of every word.

`android:capitalize="characters"` : which will capitalize every character.

Update:

As `android:capitalize` is deprecated now need to use:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

Comment: @shylendar: I hope the above capitalize attribute is deprecated now.And I am using inputType="text|textCapWords" to get what you have described above. But it doesn't do what I want and I want to work the `EditText` to work in the manner,when I apply `InputFilters.AllCaps`,where it makes all the text `Uppercase`.But I want that filter to make all the text as per the pattern I asked in the question above.

Comment: android:capitalize is deprecated . If you want to do something with your text characters you have to use android:inputType="textCapWords" for example or some of the other options

Answer (score 4):

change your input type programmatically.

If you are in View layout than use this code

```
EditText text = new EditText(context);
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS); // which will capitalize the first letter of every word.
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); //which will capitalize every character.
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); //which will capitalize the first word of each sentence.
addView(text);
```

and if you are in Activity

```
EditText text = new EditText(this);
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS); // which will capitalize the first letter of every word.
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS); //which will capitalize every character.
text.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); //which will capitalize the first word of each sentence.
setContentView(text);
```

Answer (score 3):

To make first letter capital **of every word**:

```
android:inputType="textCapWords"
```

To make first letter capital **of every sentence**:

```
android:inputType="textCapSentences"
```

To make **every letter** capital:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
txtView.setText(WordUtils.capitalize("text view")
```

*WordUtils.java*

```
public class WordUtils {

    public static String capitalize(String str) {
        return capitalize(str, (char[]) null);
    }

    public static String capitalize(String str, char... delimiters) {
        int delimLen = delimiters == null ? -1 : delimiters.length;
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(str) && delimLen != 0) {
            char[] buffer = str.toCharArray();
            boolean capitalizeNext = true;

            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; ++i) {
                char ch = buffer[i];
                if (isDelimiter(ch, delimiters)) {
                    capitalizeNext = true;
                } else if (capitalizeNext) {
                    buffer[i] = Character.toTitleCase(ch);
                    capitalizeNext = false;
                }
            }

            return new String(buffer);
        } else {
            return str;
        }
    }

    private static boolean isDelimiter(char ch, char[] delimiters) {
        if (delimiters == null) {
            return Character.isWhitespace(ch);
        } else {
            char[] arr$ = delimiters;
            int len$ = delimiters.length;

            for (int i$ = 0; i$ < len$; ++i$) {
                char delimiter = arr$[i$];
                if (ch == delimiter) {
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}​
```

Answer (score 1):

`android:capitalize` is deprecated. Use `inputType` instead.