# How to change First letter of each word to Uppercase in Textview xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

i need to change the **text="font roboto regular"** to **Font Roboto Regular** in xml itself, how to do?

```
<TextView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center"
   android:textSize="18sp"
   android:textColor="@android:color/black"
   android:fontFamily="roboto-regular"
   android:text="font roboto regular"
   android:inputType="textCapWords"
   android:capitalize="words"/>
```

Comment: I would do it in the java code

Answer (score 52):

If someone looking for `kotlin` way of doing this, then code becomes very simple and beautiful.

```
yourTextView.text = yourText.split(' ').joinToString(" ") { it.capitalize() }
```

Comment: I was about to import Apache Commons etc - this is brilliant and simple. Thanks!

Comment: As much as I love this answer how do I capitalize each word in an arraylist in kotlin?

Comment: @sanjeev `val list = listOf("abcd","xyz");
    print(list.map({ it.capitalize()}));`

Comment: @Praveena Wow thanks..! :) What if it's a model class instead of strings?

Comment: @sanjeev can you please ask a separate question by including your model class and post a link to your question here

Comment: @Praveena posted check it out.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57162265/capitalize-each-word-in-kotlin-arraylist

Comment: This is a very simple and clean solution. Thanks so much!

Comment: Don't forget to handle hyphens if you need to. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/460/do-you-capitalize-both-parts-of-a-hyphenated-word-in-a-title

Answer (score 40):

You can use this code.

```
String str = "font roboto regular";
String[] strArray = str.split(" ");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (String s : strArray) {
     String cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1);
     builder.append(cap + " ");
}
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText(builder.toString());
```

Answer (score 23):

Try this...

Method that convert first letter of each word in a string into an uppercase letter.

```
 private String capitalize(String capString){
    StringBuffer capBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    Matcher capMatcher = Pattern.compile("([a-z])([a-z]*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(capString);
    while (capMatcher.find()){
        capMatcher.appendReplacement(capBuffer, capMatcher.group(1).toUpperCase() + capMatcher.group(2).toLowerCase());
    }

    return capMatcher.appendTail(capBuffer).toString();
}
```

Usage:

```java
String chars = capitalize("hello dream world");
//textView.setText(chars);
System.out.println("Output: "+chars);
```

Result:

```
Output: Hello Dream World
```

Comment: Great! I just modified the regex, to this: `"([a-z-éá])([a-z-éá]*)"`
For those two letters with [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)

Comment: Great Answer :)

Answer (score 9):

**<kbd>KOTLIN</kbd>**

```
   val strArrayOBJ = "Your String".split(" ".toRegex()).dropLastWhile { it.isEmpty() }.toTypedArray()
                val builder = StringBuilder()
                for (s in strArrayOBJ) {
                    val cap = s.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s.substring(1)
                    builder.append("$cap ")
                }
txt_OBJ.text=builder.toString()
```

Comment: @sree add `YourTextviewObj.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);` Programmatic way

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697954/edittext-input-type-textcapsentences-not-working-on-lollipop

Comment: now i am using Kitkat device only, i changed the keyboard settings also, and i used YourTextviewObj.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES); this also, but nothing working

Comment: this is is for EditText, the question is for TextView, so no imputType is applied, the string needs to be Capitalized

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: This answer is wrong. it cannot work for TextView element. It's more for EditText element.

Comment: @user2167877 Okay. I will check

Comment: @user2167877 https://www.codesd.com/item/how-to-change-the-first-letter-of-each-word-to-uppercase-in-textview-xml.html

Comment: I took a look at the link, did you try it from your side? does't seems it will solve this question.
I can confirm:
- inputType it works for EditText (). But for TextView it gives a warning and doesn't solve the current question, Attribute android:inputType should not be used with <TextView>....
- capitalize is deprecated.

Comment: android:capitalize is deprecated.

Comment: @AmirDe I have rectified my answer.

Answer (score 5):

Modification on the accepted answer to clean out any existing capital letters and prevent the trailing space that the accepted answer leaves behind.

```java
public static String capitalize(@NonNull String input) {

    String[] words = input.toLowerCase().split(" ");
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        String word = words[i];

        if (i > 0 && word.length() > 0) {
            builder.append(" ");
        }

        String cap = word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1);
        builder.append(cap);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can use this method to do it programmatically

```
public String wordFirstCap(String str)
{
    String[] words = str.trim().split(" ");
    StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
    {
        if(words[i].trim().length() > 0)
        {
            Log.e("words[i].trim",""+words[i].trim().charAt(0));
            ret.append(Character.toUpperCase(words[i].trim().charAt(0)));
            ret.append(words[i].trim().substring(1));
            if(i < words.length - 1) {
                ret.append(' ');
            }
        }
    }

    return ret.toString();
}
```

refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21155186/3134215) if you want to do it in xml.

Comment: i need to change in xml itself

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
private String capitalize(final String line) {
   return Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(0)) + line.substring(1);
}
```

refer this [How to capitalize the first character of each word in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892765/capitalize-first-char-of-each-word-in-a-string-java)

Comment: Above code will Capitalize only the First letter in sentence.

Answer (score 1):

`android:capitalize` is deprecated.

**Follow these steps:** https://stackoverflow.com/a/31699306/4409113

> 1. Tap icon of ‘Settings’ on the Home screen of your Android Lollipop
>      Device
> 2. At the ‘Settings’ screen, scroll down to the PERSONAL section and
>      tap the ‘Language & input’ section.
> 3. At the ‘Language & input’ section, select your keyboard(which is
>      marked as current keyboard).
> 4. Now tap the ‘Preferences’.
> 5. Tap to check the ‘Auto – Capitalization’ to enable it.

And then it should work.

If it didn't, i'd rather to do that in `Java`.

Comment: i am using kitkat version device only, i tried this also, not working

Comment: Sometimes it is better to use that with `Java`.Check this link also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7573240/4409113

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use `StringTokenizer` class. The below method works for any number of words in a sentence or in the EditText view. I used this to capitalize the full names field in an app.

```java
public String capWordFirstLetter(String fullname)
{
    String fname = "";
    String s2;
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(fullname);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        s2 = tokenizer.nextToken().toLowerCase();
        if (fname.length() == 0)
            fname += s2.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s2.substring(1);
        else
            fname += " "+s2.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + s2.substring(1);
    }

    return fname;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1149869/2725203

Have a look at ACL WordUtils.

WordUtils.capitalize("your string") == "Your String"

Answer (score 1):

in kotlin, string extension

```
fun String?.capitalizeText() = (this?.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())?.split(" ")?.joinToString(" ") { if (it.length <= 1) it else it.capitalize(Locale.getDefault()) }?.trimEnd())?.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin extension function for capitalising each word

```
val String?.capitalizeEachWord
    get() = (this?.lowercase(Locale.getDefault())?.split(" ")?.joinToString(" ") {
        if (it.length <= 1) it else it.replaceFirstChar { firstChar ->
            if (firstChar.isLowerCase()) firstChar.titlecase(
                Locale.getDefault()
            ) else firstChar.toString()
        }
    }?.trimEnd())?.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the best way for achieving this used to be the capitalize() fun, but now it got depricated in kotlin. So we have an alternate for this. I've the use case where I'm getting a key from api that'll be customized at front end & will be shown apparently. The value is coming as "RECOMMENDED_OFFERS" which should be updated to be shown as "Recommended Offers".
I've created an extension function :

```
fun String.updateCapitalizedTextByRemovingUnderscore(specialChar: String): String
```

that takes a string which need to be replaced with white space (" ") & then customise the words as their 1st character would be in caps. So, the function body looks like :

```
fun String.updateCapitalizedTextByRemovingUnderscore(
 specialChar: String  = "") : String {
 var tabName = this
  // removing the special character coming in parameter & if 
     exist
  if (spclChar.isNotEmpty() && this.contains(specialChar)) {
      tabName = this.replace(spclChar, " ")
  }
  return tabName.lowercase().split(' ').joinToString(" ") {
      it.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) 
      it.titlecase(Locale.getDefault()) else it.toString() } }
}
```

How to call the extension function :

```
textView.text = 
 "RECOMMENDED_OFFERS".updateCapitalizedTextByRemovingUnderscore("_")
```

OR
`textView.text = <api_key>.updateCapitalizedTextByRemovingUnderscore("_")`

The desired output will be :
**Recommended Offers**

Hope this will help.Happy coding :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

capitalize each word

```
 public static String toTitleCase(String string) {

    // Check if String is null
    if (string == null) {
        
        return null;
    }

    boolean whiteSpace = true;
    
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(string); // String builder to store string
    final int builderLength = builder.length();

    // Loop through builder
    for (int i = 0; i < builderLength; ++i) {

        char c = builder.charAt(i); // Get character at builders position
        
        if (whiteSpace) {
            
            // Check if character is not white space
            if (!Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
                
                // Convert to title case and leave whitespace mode.
                builder.setCharAt(i, Character.toTitleCase(c));
                whiteSpace = false;
            }
        } else if (Character.isWhitespace(c)) {
            
            whiteSpace = true; // Set character is white space
        
        } else {
        
            builder.setCharAt(i, Character.toLowerCase(c)); // Set character to lowercase
        }
    }

    return builder.toString(); // Return builders text
}
```

use String to txt.setText(toTitleCase(stringVal))

don't use android:fontFamily to roboto-regular. hyphen not accept. please rename to roboto_regular.

Answer (score -3):

To capitalize each word in a sentence use the below attribute in xml of that paticular textView.

> android:inputType="textCapWords"

Comment: This cannot be used inside TextView. This is for EditText only. Check Android warning for more information.'